# How to put error messages for each dynamically created radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

Iam using javascript validation method `addClassRules` for my form to validate it.In my form I have more than 20 radio button fields those will have radio options `yes,no`.I have put same class for all of them and validates as

```
jQuery.validator.addClassRules({
        'extra_field' : {
            extra_flds_required : true              
        }
    });
    $.validator.addMethod("extra_flds_required",
                           $.validator.methods.required,"This field is required");
```

It is throwing the messages fine but breaking the Design.So I need to put those messages for each element after them.How can I do this.I have tried with `errorplacement` but no use.Please find me a way to get it done.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Even suggest me how to put messages in a specific div while using `addClassRules`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#formid").validate({
                rules:{
                                },
                               messages:{

                },
                 errorClass: "help-inline", //create seperate class for error and put here
                 errorElement: "span" //error element type 
});
```